# On Android: How to calculate row height prior to TextView creation?

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, paint

Can anyone explain correlation between `Paint.setTextSize()` and `TextView.setTextSize()` ?

I have code like this:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
paint.setTextSize(48);
paint.getTextBounds("W", 0, 1, bounds);
int rowHeight = bounds.height();
LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, rowHeight);
TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(params1);
**tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 48);**
```

but final text size in `TextView` is way bigger than `rowHeight` calculated.
I guess, my question is:
Is there any way to calculate `rowHeight` prior to `TextView` creation so that text fits by HEIGHT not width?

Thanks